# Agile tool kit oAuth facebook autentication enable

Tags: facebook, oauth, atk4

I have configured atk-addons oauth login using facebook. After entering user creantial facebook redirect to my application which leads server error

The website encountered an error while retrieving =">http://demo.test.com/admin/?page=index&auth=admin_controller_oauth_facebook&callback=1&code=AQA-7FlLE8Z-JRZFkOzYasQC88Erpz7D2NsdGcw-yw122UW_3DeEC18JnuhZQcLuW3vWP18eYDkThwxq5G2jNO-Blkv69YO3IrZx9PD3Py_G4H6Qr8BX_16UsrM7fFDbjBaQDenCuerER_6XRsVqoBwaBK40GNeLnqPxIY6qbYIy0Pm4GsYIvMuJX4s_VDGgXNY#*=*. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

How to fix this?

Comment: please study the source of the add-ons and the oAuth guide for the facebook. Addons are contributed by Agile Toolkit users and may not always work.

Comment: which version are  you on? I suggest using 4.2 - in there oAuth lib has been refactored into namespaces and is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

### From  my email to group on May 25, 2012:

Moved oauth, sni to dedicated namespaces out of misc.
They are updated and address a few issues (especially with Facebook).
Usage of **`misc/lib/Controller/OAuth.php`** is **discouraged and deprecated**. Make your adjustments.

new syntax for Facebook oAuth:

```
 $f = $this->add("oauth/Controller_OAuth_Facebook");
 $c = $this->add("sni/Controller_SNI_Facebook");
```

Remember, to reuse Facebook token to perform extra requests, use following syntax:

```
 $f->setSignatureInfo();
 $f->setAuthToken($fbtoken["access_token"], $fbtoken["expires"]);

 $c = $this->add("sni/Controller_SNI_Facebook");
 $c->setOAuth($f);
```

given, you have stored $fbtoken, which is usually retrieved by:

```
 if ($fbtoken = $f->check()){}
```

Rest of the code remains the same.